# Can't Plot Dendrogram (invalid dendrogram input error)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have 583 observations within my dataset, out of which I need to use 100 to make a Dendrogram. But I am getting the following error in the plot() function step.

how to troubleshoot/solve this?

```
##For 100 Observations
set.seed(44)
idx_100 <- sample(1:nrow(ilpd_df), 100)
distance_matrix_100 <- dist(as.matrix(ilpd_df[idx_100,-c(1,2,10,11)]), 
                        method = "euclidean") #Creates Hierarchical Clustering Solution

hc_100 <- hclust(distance_matrix_100)
plot(hc_100, hang = -1, labels=ilpd_df$Class) #CANT PLOT DUE TO INVALID INPUT ERROR
```

[image: 't plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put some minimal data that can be used to replicate the problem?

I find no issue (R 3.6.1) with `plot.hclust()`.

The following simple code

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests)^2, "cen")
class(hc)  # [1] "hclust"
plot(hc, hang = -1, main = "Sample Tree", cex = .5)
```

Produces

[image: Sample dendrogram]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using right argument to plot your dendogram. Hence Here I am sharing S3 method for plot function usage on dendograms. "hang" doesn't included in this list.

> ## S3 method for dendrogram
>
> ```
>   plot(x, type = c("rectangle", "triangle"),
>   center = FALSE,
>   edge.root = is.leaf(x) || !is.null(attr(x,"edgetext")),
>   nodePar = NULL, edgePar = list(),
>   leaflab = c("perpendicular", "textlike", "none"),
>   dLeaf = NULL, xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "s",
>   horiz = FALSE, frame.plot = FALSE, xlim, ylim, …)
> ```